# How to get the PID of a sub process across to the parent process in a bash shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process

My shell script is as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
./process1 #It will create a sub process: sub_process1
while [ condition ]; do
    break
done
kill -9 process1 and sub_process1
```

In my script, it will create a process: process1. The process1 will create a sub process: sub_process1.
Before the script finish, it need to kill the process1 and sub_process1.
It is easy to kill the process1 as it will write the PID into a file. But the sub_process1 will not. As the sub_process1 is a third-party component, I can't touch the source code.
There is a solution that can get the PID of sub_process1:

1. Enumerate all processes with the command `ps aux`;
2. Get PPID(parent process ID) for each process with the command `ps -f [PID]`. If the PPID is equal to the PID of process1, the process must be sub_process1.
   The above solution is a bit complicate. Is there a simple solution that can get sub process ID?
   Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this as Linux: `pgrep` / `pkill` to the rescue:

```bash
PID_OF_SUB_PROCESS1=$( pgrep -P $PID_OF_PROCESS1 )
pkill -P $PID_OF_PROCESS1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the process ID of `process` by running it as a background process.

```
./process1 &
pid1=$!
wait "$pid1"
```

The `wait` command waits for `process1` to exit (but not its subprocesses), like in your original script. Do note that in your original script, there's no `process1` to kill at the end: the `./process1` command finishes only when `process1` exits. It's possible that there is a child process of that process with the same name (i.e. the program may have called [`fork`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) but not [`execve`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(computing))). If you want to continue running the script as soon as `process1` itself has started, omit the `wait` line.

If you have the [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) command, it's a convenient way to kill all the children of a process. Note that the process must still be running, or must be a [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), otherwise the children's parent process ID will be reset to 1 and you can't track them this way any longer. As long as you haven't called `wait` in your script, the background process ID will remain valid.

```
./process1 &
pid1=$!
…
pkill -9 -P "$pid1"
kill -9 "$pid1"
```

Another way to track a process, its children, and their children recursively is to track the [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). The children of a process have the same process group unless they explicitly change it. On Linux, you can use the [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setsid) command to run a program in its own process group. The process group is identified by the process ID of the original process. To kill all the processes in a process group, pass the negative of the process group ID to `kill`.

```
setsid ./process1 &
pgid1=$!
…
kill -9 "-$pgid1"
```

Yet another way to track processes is to make them open a file. This works as long as the processes don't close the files, so it might not work for a program that's intended to run as a daemon. Use the command [`fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) to kill the processes that have the file open.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
process1 <"$tmpfile"
…
fuser -k -9 "$tmpfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is `kill -TERM` you **process group**.
If your script is invoked from a shell, it'll have it's own process group equal to the script's PID:

```
kill -TERM -$$
```

If it is invoked otherwise, it's process group id might not be equal to its PID:

```
kill -TERM -`ps -o pgid $$ | tail -1`
```

---

You shouldn't `kill -9` in a script or a program unless you give the program a fair chance with `kill -TERM`.

Doing a `find pid and kill it` is subject to race conditions (though they don't demonstrate frequently unless your box spawns processes like crazy). `pid`s are a moving target and unless the pid you're killing is your child and you've ensured that pid won't get recycled by not waiting on it yet (something you can hardly do in bash as far as I know), you can't be 100% sure you're killing the right process (between finding a pid and killing, the process may have died and another one may have taken the pid).

Comment: You're grabbing a random process in the process group. (The one with the highest number, which is not necessarily the one started last, since process IDs wrap (on systems where they aren't randomized).)

Answer (score 0):

`pkill` can kill processes *by name*:

```
pkill process1 && pkill sub_process1
```

should do the job.

Comment: That's a very dangerous approach, because you don't know exactly what you're killing. For example, if the same user runs several instances of the script, they will all be killed.

Comment: That's a good point.  I assumed by the names `process1` and `sub_process1` that more than one instance wouldn't be run at a time, i.e. there exists a `sub_process2`, but it's not safe to run `pkill bash`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate process group with `setsid ./process1 & pgid=$!` or using **job control**: `set -m; ./process1 & pgid=$!; set +m` and then kill the whole process group like this: `kill -- -$pgid`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740535/1243005)